# Imap to imap migration?

Tags: linux, email-server, migration, mailbox

I am currently migrating a website, and my usual method is working with mail clients, and copy the old mailbox to the new server mailbox.

But, if you have a website, with multiple mailboxes, and those mailboxes have numerous folders, the work usually takes all day.

I have searched the Internet for a far more easy and faster way, preferably open-source, but most tools are ancient, and the [Q/A here are years old](https://serverfault.com/q/259859/114962).

Wat is the faster and easier way of migrating mailboxes?

Paid tool:

- [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/)

Free Tool

- [imapfw](http://imapfw.offlineimap.org/)

**Note**:

- I have root access on the destination server, and not on the source.
- I downloaded the e-mails with the following settings

  - `mail.DONAINNAME.com`: IMAP (for receiving)
  - `smtp.DOMAINNAME.com`: SMTP (for sending)

Comment: What tools? What Q/A? You've not specified the IMAP server and the mailbox format.

Comment: Still no IMAP server and mailbox format. The reason I ask is if it's Dovecot that ships a `dsync` tool for synchronising mailboxes. Also some mailbox formats lend themselves quite well to just using archiving tools like `tar` or `rsync`, etc.

Comment: @bodgit I just checked, `file`  says they are `SMTP mail, ASCII text`. And I have founded `dovecot` process. Right now playing around with `imapcopy`.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin `asked    5 years ago`

Comment: @blade19899 It's not helpful?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin some or no longer in development, and other are proprietary software. Might look at that when all my other options are exhausted.

Comment: @blade19899 imapsync, imapcopy, etc... many links still work in that question and goto projects that are currently maintained. Seems your answers are there.

Comment: If you're migrating a website why are you touching email?

Comment: Imapsync is also gratis at https://imapsync.lamiral.info/dist/ or https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync

Answer (score 0):

**Are both IMAP daemons the same? Do they have the same mailbox format?**

If you have administrative control over these servers and their mailbox format is the same, you do not need special tools as noted by `bodgit` in the comments. You can just tar/compress the data and transfer it or rsync it, etc... just like any other data.

**There's no need for special tools**

I do suggest using compression as email is generally highly compressible. That should save you some time. Those imap tools you're using may not use compression.

If you have special requirements, please update your question for further assistance.

Comment: I think they are the same. I don't have root access on the other server. Whit the information I have can't seem to find out. But, I think they are exactly they same. Also, I cant access the dir where the emails are stored on the server, so can't rsync the data. @bodgit

Comment: @blade19899 You can't access the mailboxes? You must use the IMAP protocol? If that's true, you should put it in your question. That changes everything. Also please specify which server you do have root access on and which you don't.